# I don't seem to have Automator?

Tags: automator

From what I gather, Automator is just part of macOS. Everywhere I search seems to assume I just have it.

I go to Spotlight, type in Automator, it shows up with an app icon which gives me hope. I hit enter, and it just opens finder on an iCloud folder called Automator.

I go to Launchpad and search for Automator, see the app. Click the app. iCloud opens up ...

Ventura 13.13.1 (a) on a M1 max pro 16'

Comment: Automator is usually found in the Applications folder. Have you looked in that folder instead of using Launchpad or Spotlight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you see?

[image]

That is entirely expected. You should notice that "Automator" is the foreground app in the menubar.

[image]

This is not the Finder, but an open file dialog. There are options at the bottom of the dialog to create a New Document. Or you can just click on the File menu and select "New".

Comment: Oh wow. This is the worst design I've ever seen. I couldn't even tell it wasn't finder.

Comment: @Kalec It's a standard mac file selection dialog. You should also get this when opening TextEdit and other apps if no documents are loaded.

Comment: Yes, but I've never, to my knowledge, have the experience of something JUST opening the file selection dialog. Without anything in the background. Anything else opens the app, then a dialog. That's what I meant.